# Create a column in one dataframe based on another column in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am fairly new to R and DPLYR and I am stuck on a this issue:

I have two tables:

(1) Repairs done on cars

[image]

(2) Amount owed on each car over time

[image]

What I would like to do is create three extra columns on the repair table that gives me:
(1) the amount owed on the car when the repair was done,
(2) 3months down the road and
(3) finally last payment record on file.

And if the case where the repair date does not match with any payment record, I need to use the closest amount owed on record.

So something like:

[image]

Any ideas how I can do that?

Here are the data frames:

Repairs done on cars:

```
 df_repair <- data.frame(unique_id = 
 c("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8"),
 car_number = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3),
 repair_done = c("Front Fender","Front 
 Lights","Rear Lights","Front Fender", "Rear Fender","Rear Lights","Front 
 Lights","Front Fender"),
 YearMonth = c("2014-03","2016-03","2016-07","2015-05","2015-08","2016-01","2018-01","2018-05"))


df_owed <- data.frame(car_number = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                      YearMonth = c("2014-02","2014-05","2014-06","2014-08","2015-06","2015-12","2016-03","2016-04","2016-05","2016-06","2016-07","2016-08","2015-05","2015-08","2015-12","2016-03","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-04","2018-05","2018-09"),

amount_owed = c(20000,18000,17500,16000,10000,7000,6000,5500,5000,4500,4000,3000,10000,8000,6000,0,50000,40000,35000,30000,25000,15000))
```

Comment: @akrun Thank you for your prompt response. there were some missing commas, it should work now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `zoo` for year-months, and `tidyverse`, you could try the following. Using `left_join` add all the `df_owed` data to your `df_repair` data, by the `car_number`. You can convert your year-month columns to `yearmon` objects with `zoo`. Then, sort your rows by the year-month column from `df_owed`.

For each `unique_id` (using `group_by`) you can create your three columns of interest. The first will use the latest `amount_owed` where the owed date is prior to the service date. Then second (3 months) will use the first `amount_owed` value where the owed date follows the service date by 3 months (3/12). Finally, the most recent take just the `last` value from `amount_owed`.

Using the example data, the results differ a bit, possibly due to the data frames not matching the images in the post.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

df_repair %>%
  left_join(df_owed, by = "car_number") %>%
  mutate_at(c("YearMonth.x", "YearMonth.y"), as.yearmon) %>%
  arrange(YearMonth.y) %>%
  group_by(unique_id, car_number) %>%
  summarise(
    owed_repair_done = last(amount_owed[YearMonth.y <= YearMonth.x]),
    owed_3_months = first(amount_owed[YearMonth.y >= YearMonth.x + 3/12]),
    owed_most_recent = last(amount_owed)
  )
```